# Role defined access and dynamic role definition

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-applications, asp.net-membership

I'm implementing a role defined access system in my web-app defining authorizations in `web.config` file, something like:

```
<location path="myPage.aspx">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow roles="MY_ROLE" />
            <deny roles="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

And in `myPage.aspx` I used a lot of `if`s to define section visibility for each role.

My role structure is static, so I should not have particular problems with this implementation, but what if my roles were dynamically definied and someone can add or remove roles anytime?

Is my implementation incorrect? I'm new to this problem so I'd like to know if there is a common way to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way I implemented dynamic role-based visibility was to subclass the server controls I used and create custom controls (TextBox, Label, PlaceHolder, Panel, etc.) that had a role assigned to themselves.  When the page rendered, those controls checked their role vs. the logged in user's role, and were visible, or not, based on that check.

Each control had a default role setting, so that information didn't have to be provided for each control unless it's role was different than the default, of course.

This method really made my code-behind files much less cluttered.  And pretty easy to maintain.